# Python returns string is both str and unicode type

Tags: python, .net, unicode, ironpython

We have a .NET app that can be customized by IronPython (version 2.7.5)

Here is the script code:

```
stringToPlay = # get it from our .NET app interface toward python here. The method returns .NET string

Log.Write("isinstance(stringToPlay, unicode): ", str(isinstance(stringToPlay, unicode)))

Log.Write("isinstance(stringToPlay, str): ", str(isinstance(stringToPlay, str)))
```

Both log lines will return True ??

stringToPlay value is "Ћирилица" .

How is this possible when str and unicode should be two separate classes both inheriting from basestring?

Thank you

Comment: whats the result of `type(stringToPlay)`? your `.NET string` is `System.String`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IronPython, the `str` type and the `unicode` type are the same object. The .NET string type is unicode.

Answer (score 6):

IronPython makes no difference between `str` and `unicode`, which can be very confusing if you are used to the CPython 2 semantics. In fact, `basestring` and `unicode` are both aliases for `str`.

```
IronPython 2.7.4 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.42000 (32-bit)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> unicode
<type 'str'>
>>> basestring
<type 'str'>
```

Regarding strings, IronPython (2.X) behaves more like Python 3, with the slightly annoying fact that you can't distinguish between `unicode` and `str` if you want to decode / encode based on the type (and since it is still Python 2, there is also no `bytes`).

Comment: are there any issues then with Unify and IronPython, the way CPython 2.* has it, or just that detail you listed?

Comment: You mean Unicode, not Unify, right? The "issue" with Python 2 and Unicode is that strings initially were only encoded byte-strings (ASCII, Latin1, UTF-8 or whatever). The introduction of the `unicode` type (to represent encoding-independent strings) lead to confusion, because now you had two string types with a complex relationship. Especially calling `encode` / `decode` regardless of the type is problematic (e.g. encoding an already encoded string, decoding a unicode strings etc)

Comment: Rule of thumb: Handle all strings like unicode strings in IronPython. Never call `decode` or `encode` on string, unless you are doing IO. Then you should have no problems. (This is actually mimicing the Python 3 string handling style).